# How to type ReactNode that may have props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I've been banging my head for a few hours over this with no luck. Can't seem to find any other stackoverflow questions that help either. Basically, I have a component that takes two children nodes like so:

```
<SharedTwoColumns
  outer={{ className: "mt4 mb4" }}
  gap={<div className="h4 w4" />}
>
  <div className={isMobile ? "" : "pa3"}>Left Column</div> // first child
  <div className={isMobile ? "" : "pa3"}>Right Column</div> // second child
</SharedTwoColumns>
```

I'm trying to type the "left column" and "right column" children in a way that says that they both might have props, but not necessarily. What I have so far is:

```
const SharedTwoColumns = ({
  outer: { className: ocn, ...outer },
  children,
  gap: {
    props: { className: gcn, ...gapProps }
  }
}: {
  outer: { [x: string]: unknown; className: string };
  children: ReactNode;
  gap: { props: { [x: string]: unknown; className: string } };
}) => {

...

  const [leftColumn, rightColumn]: ReactNode[] = Children.toArray(children);
  const {
    props: { className: lcn, children: leftColumnChildren, ...leftColumnProps }
  }: ReactNode = leftColumn || {}; // TS error happens here when I hover over 'props'
```

However, this gives me the typescript error:

```
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | null'.

any
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can type this correctly when destructuring props from `leftColumn`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to use `ReactElement` type for your children, something like that:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";

interface LeftProps {
  left: string;
}
const Left = (props: LeftProps) => null;

interface RightProps {
  right: string;
}
const Right = (props: RightProps) => null;

interface LayoutProps {
  children: [ReactElement<LeftProps>, ReactElement<RightProps>];
}

function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
  // You may use React.children.toArray here but it will force you to typecast
  // in some cases (like this one with tuple)
  const left = children[0].props.left;
  const right = children[1].props.right;

  return (
    <div>
      Right: {right} Left: {left}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Left left="left" />
      <Right right="right" />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The key was not having React.children.toArray typecast for me. Had no idea it was doing that but it was fking everything up. That combined with using JSX.Element did what I needed it to do

Comment: @DannyY Just be careful with fragments and other indirect ways to pass nodes as children when not using React.children.toArray, it may break things up.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure this answers your question, but you could create an interface extending the ReactNode class.
e.g.

```
interface MyNode extends ReactNode {
  // ... your custom props here
}
```

this way, I believe you could use your custom interface to type your Columns, in a way they have all the native props of a ReactNode plus your custom props

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes some sense to me, but I'm not sure exactly how that would work. In my case, aren't `className` and `children` native ReactNode props, so shouldn't that just have worked? As for `...leftColumnProps` is there a way to use the extended interface you're suggesting to type all other possible props?

Comment: The suggestion is misleading as the ReactNode interface cannot be extended, it will fail with the following error: `An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members`